# Binding the rows of two quanteda corpus with same docvars

Tags: r, nlp, corpus, quanteda

I have two quanteda corpora objects with exactly same docvar names. The only difference between two corpora is that where one corpus' date ends, the other starts:

```
    > tail(docvars(corp_fr_before))
                                      ID                          Text_ID
621801 ParlaMint-FR_2022-06-28-O1169.u16 ParlaMint-FR-en_2022-06-28-O1169
621802 ParlaMint-FR_2022-06-28-O1169.u17 ParlaMint-FR-en_2022-06-28-O1169
621803 ParlaMint-FR_2022-06-28-O1169.u18 ParlaMint-FR-en_2022-06-28-O1169
621804  ParlaMint-FR_2022-06-29-O1170.u2 ParlaMint-FR-en_2022-06-29-O1170
621805  ParlaMint-FR_2022-06-29-O1170.u9 ParlaMint-FR-en_2022-06-29-O1170
621806 ParlaMint-FR_2022-06-29-O1170.u12 ParlaMint-FR-en_2022-06-29-O1170
                                                                                                  Title
621801 Proceedings of the debates in plenary sitting of the Assemblée Nationale, sitting: 1, 28/06/2022
621802 Proceedings of the debates in plenary sitting of the Assemblée Nationale, sitting: 1, 28/06/2022
621803 Proceedings of the debates in plenary sitting of the Assemblée Nationale, sitting: 1, 28/06/2022
621804 Proceedings of the debates in plenary sitting of the Assemblée Nationale, sitting: 2, 29/06/2022
621805 Proceedings of the debates in plenary sitting of the Assemblée Nationale, sitting: 2, 29/06/2022
621806 Proceedings of the debates in plenary sitting of the Assemblée Nationale, sitting: 2, 29/06/2022
             Date        Body            Term
621801 2022-06-28 Lower house 16e législature
621802 2022-06-28 Lower house 16e législature
621803 2022-06-28 Lower house 16e législature
621804 2022-06-29 Lower house 16e législature
621805 2022-06-29 Lower house 16e législature
621806 2022-06-29 Lower house 16e législature
                                                   Session Meeting   Sitting Agenda Subcorpus
621801 Session ordinaire 2021-2022 (CRSANR5L16S2022O1N169)       - 1. séance      - COVID,War
621802 Session ordinaire 2021-2022 (CRSANR5L16S2022O1N169)       - 1. séance      - COVID,War
621803 Session ordinaire 2021-2022 (CRSANR5L16S2022O1N169)       - 1. séance      - COVID,War
621804 Session ordinaire 2021-2022 (CRSANR5L16S2022O1N170)       - 2. séance      - COVID,War
621805 Session ordinaire 2021-2022 (CRSANR5L16S2022O1N170)       - 2. séance      - COVID,War
621806 Session ordinaire 2021-2022 (CRSANR5L16S2022O1N170)       - 2. séance      - COVID,War
          Lang Speaker_role Speaker_MP Speaker_minister Speaker_party
621801 English        Guest      notMP      notMinister             -
621802 English      Regular         MP      notMinister             -
621803 English        Guest      notMP      notMinister             -
621804 English      Regular         MP      notMinister            RE
621805 English      Regular         MP      notMinister           DEM
621806 English      Regular         MP      notMinister            RE
                      Speaker_party_name Party_status      Party_orientation Speaker_ID
621801                                 -            -                      -   PA606171
621802                                 -            -                      -   PA721908
621803                                 -            -                      -   PA606171
621804                       Renaissance            -                 Centre   PA721908
621805 Démocrate (MoDem et Indépendants)            - Centre to centre-right   PA331582
621806                       Renaissance            -                 Centre   PA721908
            Speaker_name Speaker_gender Speaker_birth      dateX year_month year
621801  Ferrand, Richard              M          1962 2022-06-28 2022-06-01 2022
621802 Braun-Pivet, Yaël              F          1970 2022-06-28 2022-06-01 2022
621803  Ferrand, Richard              M          1962 2022-06-28 2022-06-01 2022
621804 Braun-Pivet, Yaël              F          1970 2022-06-29 2022-06-01 2022
621805  Vigier, Philippe              M          1958 2022-06-29 2022-06-01 2022
621806 Braun-Pivet, Yaël              F          1970 2022-06-29 2022-06-01 2022
> 

    > head(docvars(corp_fr_after))

                                  ID                          Text_ID
1  ParlaMint-FR_2017-07-05-E1002.u83 ParlaMint-FR-en_2017-07-05-E1002
2  ParlaMint-FR_2017-07-05-E1002.u98 ParlaMint-FR-en_2017-07-05-E1002
3 ParlaMint-FR_2017-07-06-E1003.u103 ParlaMint-FR-en_2017-07-06-E1003
4 ParlaMint-FR_2017-07-06-E1003.u126 ParlaMint-FR-en_2017-07-06-E1003
5 ParlaMint-FR_2017-07-06-E1003.u129 ParlaMint-FR-en_2017-07-06-E1003
6 ParlaMint-FR_2017-07-06-E1003.u131 ParlaMint-FR-en_2017-07-06-E1003
                                                                                             Title
1 Proceedings of the debates in plenary sitting of the Assemblée Nationale, sitting: 2, 05/07/2017
2 Proceedings of the debates in plenary sitting of the Assemblée Nationale, sitting: 2, 05/07/2017
3 Proceedings of the debates in plenary sitting of the Assemblée Nationale, sitting: 3, 06/07/2017
4 Proceedings of the debates in plenary sitting of the Assemblée Nationale, sitting: 3, 06/07/2017
5 Proceedings of the debates in plenary sitting of the Assemblée Nationale, sitting: 3, 06/07/2017
6 Proceedings of the debates in plenary sitting of the Assemblée Nationale, sitting: 3, 06/07/2017
        Date        Body            Term
1 2017-07-05 Lower house 15e législature
2 2017-07-05 Lower house 15e législature
3 2017-07-06 Lower house 15e législature
4 2017-07-06 Lower house 15e législature
5 2017-07-06 Lower house 15e législature
6 2017-07-06 Lower house 15e législature
                                                       Session Meeting   Sitting Agenda
1 Première session extraordinaire 2017 (CRSANR5L15S2017E1N002)       - 2. séance      -
2 Première session extraordinaire 2017 (CRSANR5L15S2017E1N002)       - 2. séance      -
3 Première session extraordinaire 2017 (CRSANR5L15S2017E1N003)       - 3. séance      -
4 Première session extraordinaire 2017 (CRSANR5L15S2017E1N003)       - 3. séance      -
5 Première session extraordinaire 2017 (CRSANR5L15S2017E1N003)       - 3. séance      -
6 Première session extraordinaire 2017 (CRSANR5L15S2017E1N003)       - 3. séance      -
  Subcorpus    Lang Speaker_role Speaker_MP Speaker_minister Speaker_party Speaker_party_name
1 Reference English      Regular         MP      notMinister             -                  -
2 Reference English      Regular         MP      notMinister             -                  -
3 Reference English      Regular         MP      notMinister             -                  -
4 Reference English      Regular         MP      notMinister             -                  -
5 Reference English      Regular         MP      notMinister             -                  -
6 Reference English      Regular         MP      notMinister             -                  -
  Party_status Party_orientation Speaker_ID     Speaker_name Speaker_gender Speaker_birth
1            -                 -   PA606212 Collard, Gilbert              M          1948
2            -                 -   PA606212 Collard, Gilbert              M          1948
3            -                 -   PA606212 Collard, Gilbert              M          1948
4            -                 -   PA606212 Collard, Gilbert              M          1948
5            -                 -   PA606212 Collard, Gilbert              M          1948
6            -                 -   PA606212 Collard, Gilbert              M          1948
       dateX year_month year
1 2017-07-05 2017-07-01 2017
2 2017-07-05 2017-07-01 2017
3 2017-07-06 2017-07-01 2017
4 2017-07-06 2017-07-01 2017
5 2017-07-06 2017-07-01 2017
6 2017-07-06 2017-07-01 2017
```

how can I merge these two corpus , using a function like rbind, while keeping the docvars?  I tried + operator or c(), and rbind, none were helpful.

Comment: `c()` should work and it should concatenate the docvars. Can you supply a reproducible example or at the least, output including the version number?

Comment: Please include a link to the datasets, so that they can be loaded into an R environment.